# How to set default ALSA input/output in pusleaudio on LibreELEC?

Tags: kodi, alsa, openelec, pulseaudio

I'm using *Raspberry Pi 3 Model B* as LibreElec for Kodi. My Pi is connect on TV on HDMI. In kodi, when I select audio outputs HDMI or Jack it play sound well. But when I select Pulseaudio, it don't play any sound.

I'm following the tutorial: https://wiki.libreelec.tv/pulseaudio to use the PI as Bluetooth Audio Receiving. I could connect my Phone on Bluetooth and set it as default source.

When I do `pactl info` my default Sink is `auto_null`.
In the tutorial it's write we should set the output device `pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.platform-aml_m8_snd.45.analog-stereo`. But I don't know how to discover this **alsa_output.**

When I do `pactl list short sinks` I only find `0  auto_null  module-null-sinks.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz  SUSPENDED`

I also understood that I have to set my parameters on `/storage/.config/pulse-daemon.conf.d/custom.conf`. But for example idk how to disable `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` (*Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long*) that is write on `/etc/pulse/system.pa`.

What I want is playing Kodi using Pulseaudio output device. And then use my phone to steam music by Pulseaudio[bluetooth] > kodi > TV[HDMI].